# Emacs refusing to save changes

Tags: emacs

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and I was trying get started using emacs. However, I cannot get any settings saved because it claims that it was launched with a -q flag. This behavior is the same from both command line and GUI launching. Please help.

UPDATE: The issue is gone, but I am not sure why. Even though I had the application installed, I could still add it from the software center (I installed it with `sudo apt-get install emacs`) Can someone help me figure out what the hell happened?

Comment: Re: your update: I'm no Emacs theologian, but when a miracle occurs, it's best to thank the Saint IGNUcius for His grace in alleviating our suffering and setting things right. Asking the Devil to explain his past deceitful bugs and errors, while tempting, can never come to any good. It also tends to lead the user down the path toward vim, something every emacs user should avoid! I'm overjoyed that you have been blessed by St. IGNUcius's good graces and that He bestowed a spontaneous bug-fix upon you. May your emacs experience from here on be bug-free and productive.